# Не работает --headless firefox selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Программа перестаёт искать элементы на странице. Ошибка, что объект не обнаружен. Без headless программа работает корректно

```
options = Options()
        options.binary = r'files/firefox/firefox'
        firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        #firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
        options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap,
                               executable_path=r"files/firefox/geckodriver", firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
        driver.get("????.com")
        driver.execute_script('window.stop();')
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1000000).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH, '/html/body/section/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

А принципиально использовать фокс? Скажем, при

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='venv/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

тоже самое будет?
И еще тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031706/selenium-firefox-headless-returns-different-results/59033268#59033268 обсуждают, что фокс дурит с размером окна.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver 

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()

options.add_argument("-headless")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].